Kong Gateway Enterprise Free Mode on Kubernetes
I am trying to deploy the Kong Gateway (Enterprise in Free mode) on the EKS following this guide https://docs.konghq.com/gateway/latest/install/kubernetes/proxy/
Stuck at the step install Kong Manager, completed this guide https://docs.konghq.com/gateway/latest/install/kubernetes/manager/, I have Kong Manager up, but the Workspace is not working yet, the Manager neither works. Please advise a clue how to fix? anything related to the RBAC which is not available in free mode?


Please advise how to fix the issue "error calculating" on the Manager, "Data cannot be displayed due to an error." on the Workspace

I figured out my issue, I found that I got and / at the end of admin_gui_url and admin_gui_api_url. That / causes the issue "not found"


env:
  admin_gui_url: http://kong-manager.abc.com/
  admin_gui_api_url: http://kong-admin.acb.com/



